# 301 redirects for asp pages to html

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, redesign

So I've redesigned a site that was built comprising of solely `.asp` pages and redid it using `.html` pages. I deleted the old site and uploaded the new, and uploaded my `.htaccess` file with code along the lines of:

```
Redirect 301 /studio.asp /studio.html
```

etc.

I was expecting that when I clicked on a google entry that it would redirect the old `/studio.asp` page to `/studio.html` but it doesn't? What am I doing wrong? I should say that I've tried to keep the filenames and old structure as much as possible the same in the redesign, but it's still showing the old `.asp` pages. Or have I missed something entirely here? Should my old site still be live in order for the redirects to work? Does it even matter that the old file extension is `.asp`? It is still sitting on the same URL as well.

Comment: What is your OS and web server? .htaccess is an Apache directive. Are you running Apache?

Comment: in case you're running an Apache server you need to precise the full url like this : `Redirect 301 /studio.asp https://example.com/studio.html`. [Anyway is this link what you're looking for ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381026/how-to-redirect-with-asp-classic)

Comment: If this is the same server that was running the ASP pages then this is more likely to be IIS, not Apache. @pjmg Since Apache 2.2.6 you don't _need_ to specify an absolute URL as the target.

Comment: Oh good to know ty @MrWhite

Comment: No, the host provider migrated the site to a linux server from a windows one as he said I couldn't use htaccess on it.

Comment: Thanks @pjmg. The link you provide is for redirecting to a new URL, but I have kept the same url. I just wondered if I needed to redirect because all off the old site was in .asp and as I've rebuilt it, they all now end in .html. A lot of the old google entries for url.com/studio.asp are still going to that page, which now doesn't exist as they are now.html, so I'm worried that people will think that the site is down. How can I rectify this?

Comment: @mhcoder36 The link provided above is for redirecting on a Windows/IIS/ASP server. You state you are now on a Linux server (assume Apache). And the domain (URL) remains the same. In that case, there is nothing seemingly wrong with the `.htaccess` directive posted - so why isn't this doing anything? Have you confirmed that `.htaccess` files are enabled on the server (although the host seems to imply they are)? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? What happens exactly when you request `/studio.asp`?

Comment: @MrWhite When I request /studio.asp, I get a "This domain name has been registered with YourSupportServices.co.uk" page. I've deleted all of the .asp pages so I could upload my new website - could this be an issue? Does an old site still need to be live for redirects to work?? Or maybe it's just taking a while for google's spiders to crawl there way around??

Comment: @mhcoder36 That's strange. So, `/studio.asp` doesn't even reach your site, but `/studio.html` works OK?! It is correct to have deleted the old `.asp` pages (although this should not matter, providing you implement redirects). No, the old site does not need to be live, providing the domain has not changed. Google's crawlers are irrelevant. The redirect should be happening on your site, not Google. When you request `/studio.asp` directly, this has nothing to do with Google.

Comment: Yes. It still tries to load studio.asp rather than studio.html. To be honest, recently the google results have been throwing up a link to the homepage which now goes through to the correct new site's homepage but it's still serving up this old studio page.

Comment: Are you perhaps seeing a cached response? Although the response message you just quoted, "This domain name has been registered with...." would seem to imply your server has not been set up correctly (or the DNS is still propagating)? To confirm, when you request `/studio.html`, the correct page is displayed?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes I think they are cached responses, but I thought the whole idea of redirecting was that cached links like this can be redirected to the new page on load? you can see for yourself if you google sublime pilates and click on the links for studio. The main homepage link is fine but there are other pages as well such as pilates-and-fitness that go through to the old cached pages. And yes, studio.html is working fine.

Comment: That's not a cached response. That would seem to be the standard "404 Not Found" response from your server!? Request `/anything-that-does-not exist` and you get the same response. (You said it was "still showing the old `.asp` pages" - that does not seem to be the case?) And these responses are coming from an "Nginx" server (possibly a front-end proxy) - not Apache? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Try putting some _nonsense_ at the start - do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry I meant that the links were still showing the .asp links, not that the pages were showing physically. All I want is for any old google link to forward on to the relevant .html page, so that people don't think the site is down. Is this possible, or do I just need to delete all these old links from google if it's not possible?

Comment: "Is this possible..." - Yes, this should be possible. But there is something else going on or not working correctly here. You may need to contact your host. As asked in my previous comment... Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Try putting some nonsense at the start - do you get an error? Have you confirmed you are now on an Apache webserver?

Comment: Through (bad) experience, I learned how to avoid this problem completely.  Now, all my externally visible links are of the form `https://sitename/path/`, and all my pages are stored as `/path/index.asp`, or `/path/index.html`, or `/path/index.php`, or whatever.  I.e. *all* my pages are called `index.*` and all canonical links to them end with a "/".  That way I can change the implementation of any page at any time without affecting anything anywhere else, and Google's indexing continues working without any modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The response you are seeing for the old `.asp` pages would appear to be the standard 404 response on your server (or rather a front-end Nginx proxy by the looks). You seem to get the same response regardless of what non-existent page you request. So, this is not limited to `.asp` pages. This 404 response is a "domain holding" page with external third party adverts - which is not desirable, but maybe something which is forced on you by your host?

Edit: Whilst requesting other 404 pages I occasionally got a "502 Bad Gateway" or "503 Service Unavailable" response. This is also not desirable (and not *normal*).

**You need to check with your host what is going on here.**

You do not need the old site to be present in order to implement redirects from the old URLs. That is the whole point of an external redirect.

The host said that they "migrated the site to a linux server from a windows one ... so as to be able to use htaccess". This would imply you are being migrated to Apache (or perhaps LiteSpeed).

I assume this is a "shared" server. In which case `.htaccess` files should already be enabled.

If the `.htaccess` file exists in the document root of your site, then the `Redirect` directive you posted in the question, namely:

```
Redirect 301 /studio.asp /studio.html
```

really is all you require to redirect from `/studio.asp` to `/studio.html`.

If this is not happening, then again, you need to query this with your host.

---

> **UPDATE:** My host provider reckons it's because I have the `.rtf` extension on the file as the file is enabled. The thing is, I deleted it on my desktop so it just shows `.htaccess` but it still shows as `.htaccess.rtf` when uploaded to the server. ... I've used TextEdit on the mac.

Yes, that is certainly a problem! If the file is called `.htaccess.rtf` on the server then it's simply never going to be processed by Apache and it won't do anything (which is the behaviour you are seeing - nothing). It must be called `.htaccess` - no more; no less with a dot as the first character. But also, it must not be formatted as an RTF (Rich Text Format) file. It must be "plain text", preferably UTF-8 encoded.

1. Make sure that your Mac is displaying file extensions:
   https://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/10/29/how-to-show-or-hide-filename-extensions-in-os-x-yosemite/
2. Make sure TextEdit is configured to edit plain text files:
   https://youtu.be/zCN75v4Bbdk

Recreate the file locally with the correct filename. Delete the incorrectly named file on the server and reupload!

<sup>(How did you edit and upload all the other files on your site?!)</sup>

Comment: I've just googled the site again and clicked on the studio link that appears and it's now going to the correct studio page! So I guess the redirects are working and that it just took a while to implement? Although I doubt it should take a week and a half should it? Either way, it's working, so thank you loads for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not working for me still - there are no redirects as far as I can see? Are you being redirected (check the network traffic in the browser), or are you clicking on the newly indexed `/studio.html` page in the SERPs? Request `/studio.asp` and you are not redirected - you just get the 404 Not Found page as mentioned above. The same for the other indexed pages... `/aromatherapy.asp`, `/reiki.asp`, `/chakras.asp`, etc. etc. You don't need Google to test this. Just request these pages directly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've raised this with my host and am now awaiting their response.

Comment: My host provider reckons it's because I have the .rtf extension on the file as the file is enabled. The thing is, I deleted it on my desktop so it just shows .htaccess but it still shows as .htaccess.rtf when uploaded to the server. I've searched google for an answer to this but can't find one. I've used TextEdit on the mac.

Comment: Yes, that is certainly a problem! If the file is not named `.htaccess` (exactly) on the server then it's not going to do anything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's now working perfectly. I guess I never noticed it had the .rtf extension on the server as it looked right locally for me. I ended up using sublime text and deleting the extension which worked better than text edit. Anyway, thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Consider marking an answer as "accepted" if it helped solve the problem (helps other readers and removes the question from the unanswered question queue). Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Ok, I shall do that!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, inspect your log files: what happens on accessing studio.asp?

I very suspect that to make the expected schema work you should maintain the previous IIS server too, so page like studio.asp really exist.

What else could happen? If my suspicion is wrong and with the server/file circumstances is everything ok, Googlebot could be a bit lazy and just don't crawl your redirect yet. That could be the cause, why you don't see an expected redirect if clicking studio.asp in SERP.

Comment: `"Googlebot could be a bit lazy and just don't crawl your redirect yet. That could be the cause, why you don't see an expected redirect if clicking studio.asp in SERP"` - this has nothing to do with whether Googlebot has crawled the redirect yet. The redirect occurs on the target site, not by Google.

Comment: `"I very suspect that to make the expected schema work you should maintain the previous IIS server too, so page like studio.asp really exist."` - If you are implementing redirects, why would the old site need to exist? (By all accounts, the domain name has not changed.)

Comment: @MrWhite `this has nothing to do with whether Googlebot has crawled the redirect yet` - surey it does. TS asks `I was expecting that when I clicked on a google entry that it would redirect the old`. If Gbot doesn't crawled it yet, or doesn't understand, then then old page remains in SERP.

Comment: But the main problem is that there is no working redirect for Gbot to crawl in the first place. If there was a working redirect in place on the website, then any user clicking an old result in the SERP _would be redirected_ to the new URL - regardless of whether Gbot has crawled that redirect or not.